# find(Search) particular named file from QFilesystemmodel

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

I am newbie in Qt. I am using QFileSystemModel in QTreeview to explore the contents of the drives. I want to find a particular named file from anyone drive using this QFileSystemModel. Now, Is there any way to find that particular file from this model ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`QFileSystemModel` doesn't provide any search methods. You should use [QDirIterator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdiriterator.html) instead.

```
QString find_file(QString dir, QString name) {
  QDirIterator it(dir, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    it.next();
    if (it.fileName() == name) {
      return it.filePath();
    }
  }
  return QString();
}
```

You can use `QFileSystemModel::index` method to convert file path to model index.